# Connect to Bluetooth Device By Name Programmatically in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

My intention is to make my android app that only connects to the specific bluetooth name. For Example, I want to connect it to "ABC" only . I tried

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
      // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
      // object and its info from the Intent.
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      // HERE
    }
  }
};
```

How DO I specifically get the name to the output?

Comment: start Bluetooth search, when finding the device - check it's name. If it matches what you want - connect.

Comment: sounds good, let me try and will update you.

Comment: on android developer page there is example how to use Bluetooth API, after reading it I am sure you will be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
      // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
      // object and its info from the Intent.
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      String deviceName = device.getName();
      // 
      // use try-catch to keep tying on the logic -- John Melody added
      try {
        if (deviceName.contains("somethingsomething")) {
          System.out.println(String.format("Ok %s", deviceName));
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    //
    }
  }
};
```

Checkout[this][1] link

[1] : https: //developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#FindingDevices